# How can i use mysql_real_escape_string in array

Tags: php

I'm using an array, and i want to insert mysql_real_escape_string into my POST's

How can i do that?

```
  $add = array();  

  foreach($add as $key=>$_POST) 
  { 

     $add['description']  = $_POST['description'];
     $add['logo']  = $_POST['logo'];    
     $add['status']  = $_POST['status'];
     $add['localization']  = $_POST['localization'];
     $add['contract_type']  = $_POST['contract_type'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
foreach($add as $key=>$_POST) { 

 $add['description']  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
 $add['logo']  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['logo']);    
 $add['status']  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']);
 $add['localization']  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['localization']);
 $add['contract_type']  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contract_type']);
}
```

**Note**:-  `mysql_*` has been deprecated use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Answer (score 0):

Make a function like this

```
function safe($value) { 
   return mysqli_real_escape_string($value); 
}
```

and then

```
$add = array();  

 foreach($add as $key=>$_POST) { 

 $add['description']  = safe($_POST['description']);
 $add['logo']  = safe($_POST['logo']);    
 $add['status']  = safe($_POST['status']);
 $add['localization']  = safe($_POST['localization']);
 $add['contract_type']  = safe($_POST['contract_type']);
}
```